# Backup of SQL Server 2008R2 database is huge

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I am backing up a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with the intention of restoring it elsewhere. When I back it up using the backup wizard (right click tasks, backup ) the size of the resulting backup is much larger than I know the database should be (c45Gb when there is only about 5Gb of data)

How can I get a reasonably sized backup created to transfer and restore elsewhere?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: The backup includes the transaction log.  If the database is using the FULL recovery model, you need to schedule regular transaction log backups to meet your recovery objectives and keep the transaction log reasonably sized.

Comment: Flagged as off topic with the suggestion that this get moved to Super User. There's no programming aspect to this question - it's just a question about using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a smaller backup by going to the options tab on the backup and set the compression to 'compress backup', I also chose Overwrite all existing backup sets and Backed up to a new  media set name.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ty221 - How does this not answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Full backups contain all pages in use plus the part of the log that covers the time span that the backup ran for (approximately). It would surprise me if you generated 40GB of log during a backup of 5GB. At this point I'd check if you really backed up the right database. Or, maybe the destination file already contained other backups.

You say:

> I created a smaller backup by going to the options tab on the backup
>   and set the compression to 'compress backup', I also chose Overwrite
>   all existing backup sets and Backed up to a new media set name.

Apparently, the existing file already contained data. It is unlikely that compression is responsible for the bulk of the savings.